# Targeting `el` and `$el` correctly

Tags: backbone.js

I have a `#root` DOM object with many `.element` children:

```
<div id='root'>
  <div class='element'>
    <span>Element 1</span>
  </div>
  <div class='element'>
    <span>Element 2</span>
  </div>
  <div class='element'>
    <span>Element 3</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want a Backbone View instance for every `.element`. This is what I have tried:

```
var ElementView = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize: function () {
    _.bindAll(this, 'showText');
    this.setElement('.element');
  },
  events: {
    'click span': 'showText'
  },
  showText: function () {
    console.log('You have clicked ' + $el.text());
  }
});
```

I initialize my views as follows:

```
new ElementView({ model: modelInstance });
```

The problem is that `.element` is not precise enough, `$el` will be `$('.element')[0]` for every initialisation. How should I deal with the situation where many elements have the same CSS selector?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Initialize your views with their associated elements :

```
$(".element").each(function(ix,el) {
    new ElementView({ model: modelInstance , el:el });
});
```

Dont' forget to remove `this.setElement('.element');` in the `initialize` code.